# GWT Linechart options

Tags: gwt, google-visualization, jsni, linechart

I need to set different line width to different series in a chart. This can be done using the **series** option here http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart.html#Configuration_Options . However this option is not available in GWT which leads to my question.

I could:

1. Write a wrapper for GWT. http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationNewWrapper
2. Use the Options.set(...) method. http://gwt-google-apis.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/visualization/1.1/com/google/gwt/ajaxloader/client/Properties.html#set%28java.lang.String,%20com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject%29

The problem for both those alternatives is that I don't know how to do either when the series option takes an object:

```
series: [{color: 'black', visibleInLegend: false},{}, {}, {color: 'red', visibleInLegend: false}]
series: {0:{color: 'black', visibleInLegend: false}, 3:{color: 'red', visibleInLegend: false}}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method 2 is easier:

You can use `Options.set()` and pass another `Options` instance.

At least for the second option type.
`series: {0:{color: 'black', visibleInLegend: false}, 3:{color: 'red', visibleInLegend: false}}` you can use following code:

```
Options options = Options.create();
options.setTitle(title);
Options series_options = Options.create();
series1_options = Options.create();
series1_options.set("color","black");
series_options.set("0",series1_options);
options.set("series",series_options);
```

Comment: Wow, wouldn't have tried that, but it works perfectly. A bit messy but it works :)