# How do I create ComboChart in google GWT(Java) with multiple Series and a secondary scale?

Tags: java, gwt

Adding Multiple series to the ComboChart with different graph types is straightforward, but I am not able get the targetAxisIndex set against a particular series. Any thoughts/Working examples for this? I looked at the google charting tools javascript examples, but not able to translate the same to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020465/gwt-linechart-options/9021847#9021847).

```
private Options createOptionsChart() {
    Options options = Options.create();
    options.set("isStacked", true);
    //set some options

    Options series_options = Options.create();
    series1_options = Options.create();
    series1_options.set("color","black");
    series_options.set("0",series1_options);
    options.set("series",series_options);
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Though this is not a direct answer, my question itself should have been more clear. I meant to display a second y-axis using the "targetAxisIndex" option. But this nested arrangement of Options is something I didn't know, which eventually helped me get what I needed.