# GWT and Visualization API options

Tags: gwt

I am making a line chart using GWT and the google Visualization API (https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) with the following code

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.SimplePanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.AbstractDataTable.ColumnType;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.DataTable;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.LineChart;
import com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.LineChart.Options;

public class TestPlot {

Widget pie;
static SimplePanel S;
public Widget getLineChart() {
    S = new SimplePanel();

    DataTable data = DataTable.create();
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "X");
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Chanel 1");
    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Channel 2");
    data.addRows(2);
    data.setValue(0, 0, "0");
    data.setValue(0, 1, 0);
    data.setValue(0, 2, 0);
    data.setValue(1, 0, "1");
    data.setValue(1, 1, 4);
    data.setValue(1, 2, 1);

    Options options = Options.create();
    options.setWidth(1000);
    options.setHeight(700);
    options.setTitle("Test");
    options.setEnableTooltip(false);
    options.setPointSize(0);

    LineChart pie = new LineChart(data, options);
    //pie.draw(createTable2());
    S.add(pie);
    return S;
}     
}
```

I would like to set some options shown on https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart that do not have a method options.setWhatever().  It seems that I need to use the options.setOption(option, value) but I can't get it to work.  For example how would I set the two lines from the above example to red and green.  I tried:

```
options.setOption("colors", "['red','green']");
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need only to change the colors of lines,

You have to create your own Options class with color and hae to add that to the main options

```
series1_options = Options.create();
series1_options.set("color","black");
series_options.set("0",series1_options);
options.set("series",series_options);
```

Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020465/gwt-linechart-options).Do not go for wrapper option,you may face many issues than the main(*I Faced*).

Comment: Eclipse tells me that set is not a method, but setOption is (with the correct signitures) but I can't change my first series black with your code and that change. I am using com.google.gwt.visualization.client.visualizations.LineChart.Options;

Comment: I realized that I was using 1.0.2 (which was downloaded from the page that the tutorial points to) but 1.1.2 should be used (which is on the google code download page.

Comment: This answer and the referring link answered my questions.  Thanks