# GWT/google visualization wrapper 2 y-axis

Tags: java, gwt, visualization, axis, linechart

I am using GWT 2.5 and the JAVA Google Visualization wrapper 1.1.2.

I try to create a line Chart with 2 y-axis (it works fine with one). I know it is possible in pure javascript but I don't find any answer for java.

I read [GWT Linechart options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020465/gwt-linechart-options) and try this :

```
AxisOptions axes[] = new AxisOptions[2];
axes[0] = firstAxis;
axes[1] = secondAxis;
options.set("vAxes", axes); //not working
```

AxisOptions are correctly created and using code like the one below works fine :

```
options.set("vAxis", firstAxis);
```

Someone knows how to do a 2 Y-axis line chart ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the second version of the SO thread you referenced?
If you must pass an array to the AxisOption you have to use a `JsArray` instead.

Something like this:

```
JsArray<AxisOptions> axes= AxisOptions.createArray().cast();
axes.push(firstAxis);
axes.push(secondAxis);
options.set("vAxes",axes);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I missed the point and with this JsArray it is fine. 
Besides that, I just had to add some properties to the options of the Line Chart and everything works.  
Properties firstSerie = Properties.create();
Properties secondSerie = Properties.create();
firstSerie.set("targetAxisIndex","0");
secondSerie.set("targetAxisIndex","1");
series.push(serie);
series.push(serie2);
options.set("series", series);